# Set windows 10 certificate import wizard as default when opening files

Tags: windows, certificate

I used nexus personal as default to open .p12 files. I want to reverse this and open this filetype with the certificate import wizard. This is the default option when opening (doubleclicking) a certificate: A new window appears and you chose where to install it. But I can't chose mmc or the certificate import wizard as default program to open .p12 files with. I can start mmc manually and import the certificate, but that's not an option to work with for our clients.

Does anybody know how this works?

Answer (score 2):

1. File *Properties* → *Opens with*: → *Change...*
2. *More Apps* → *Look for another app on this PC*
3. *File name*: → Change *Programs* to *All Files*
4. Select: `C:\Windows\System32\cryptext.dll`

---

Merging the following into the Registry will auto-recognize `.pem` extensions as certs:

- **CLI:**

  ```bsh
  Reg Add "HKCR\.pem" /t REG_SZ /d "CERFile"
  Reg Add "HKCR\.pem" /v "Content Type" /t REG_SZ /d "application/x-x509-ca-cert"
  ```
- **`PEM-Association.reg`:**

  ```reg
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pem]
  @="CERFile"
  "Content Type"="application/x-x509-ca-cert"
  ```